# Why is identity null when using .net core 2 AuthorizationHandler in iframe

Tags: c#, iframe, asp.net-core, authorization, asp.net-core-2.0

I have the following `AuthorizationRequirement` and `AuthorizationHandler` that is registered with DI and is working just fine. However, when an action with `[Authorize(Policy = "ConfirmedEmail")]` is called within an iframe (same origin), `context.User.Identity.Name` is allways NULL and therefore so is `user`. Does anyone have any idea why this is, and more importantly how to fix it?

When the exact same action is called directly (outside an iframe), `context.User.Identity.Name` is correct and the user lookup succeeds.

```
public class ConfirmedEmailRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement { }

    public class ConfirmedEmailHandler : AuthorizationHandler<ConfirmedEmailRequirement>
    {
        private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;

        public ConfirmedEmailHandler(UserManager<User> userManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
        }

        protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, ConfirmedEmailRequirement requirement)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(context.User);
            if (user?.EmailConfirmed == true)
            {
                context.Succeed(requirement);
            }
            else
            {
                context.Fail();
            }
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**:
I have noticed that although both iframe and non iframe request have the same session cookie, the non iframe request includes a `Core.Identity.Application` cookie, the iframe request does not. I don't know the significance of this or what is causing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally managed to get identity to work within an iframe using the following:

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => {
    options.Cookie.Name = "MyAuthCookie";
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None; //<THIS!!!
});
```

Hope this saves someone a lot of head scratching some day.